# How to output response body in Rspec along with description

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to use Rspec's HTML formatter to generate API documentation, for this purpose I think I need to make changes in HTML formatter which I can easily make by over ridding example_passed funtion but problem is getting the test's response into that function via RSpec::Core:Example, I have tried to follow this example http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/21/generating-documentation-from-specs/ but I get error in **InstrumentSpecs**

```
RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::WrongScopeError: `example` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).
```

My **InstrumentSpecs** look like this

```
require 'action_dispatch'
require 'action_controller'

module InstrumentSpecs
  module ::ActionController::TestCase::Behavior
    alias_method :process_without_logging, :process

    def process(action, http_method = 'GET', parameters = nil)
      version, route = described_class.to_s.match(/Api::V1::(\w+)Controller/)[1..2].collect(&:downcase)
      curl = "curl "
      # parameters.each {|key, value| curl << "-d \"#{key}=#{CGI.escape(value)}\" " } if parameters.present?
      curl << "-X #{http_method} "
      curl << "https://api.host.example/#{version}/#{route} "
      example.metadata[:curl] = curl

      response = process_without_logging(action, http_method, parameters)
      example.metadata[:response] = "#{response.status} #{response.body}"

      response
    end
  end
end
```

Error occurs on line below

```
example.metadata[:curl] = curl
```

My spec looks like this

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Api::V1::UsersController do
  render_views
  describe 'when user is logged in' do
    let(:user) {create(:user)}
    before do
      sign_in user
    end

    describe 'GET #index' do
      it 'gets index page' do
        create(:user)
        get :index, format: :json
        is_expected.to respond_with :ok
      end
    end
  end  
end
```

I am using rails 4.2.5 and rspec 3.4

Comment: `is_expected.to respond_with 200`

Comment: @RajarshiDas what are you trying to suggest?

Comment: outside of scope  describe 'when user is logged in' do then again a describe with in that describe ? check the scope properly

Comment: I think scopes are alright I am following this https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/controller-spec